# How to constrain operators of generic parameters in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to write an instrumental generic function

```cs
    public static T F<T>(T a, T b) 
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

But, it need the parameter has operators like +, -, etc. 
How do I implement this?

Comment: [see this link] [1] it will answer this
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122611/12280923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without a bit of tricking, because, as you may have notices, there's no way you can make the compiler know that instances of the unknown type T can be added. The following works, though:

```
public static T F<T>(T a, T b) 
{
    dynamic a1 = a;
    dynamic a2 = b;
    return a1 + b1;
}
```

It has a few issues, though: Since the operation is compiled at runtime, it may be slower than a default add, and it will compile, no matter what T is. Only if *at runtime* T has no operator+, it will throw an exception.